# Flutter: Strange behavior on hot-reload when using const

Tags: flutter

The following piece of code generates the below image (the shadowed container with the yellow square inside it):

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
    child: SwitchPreview(
        mode: enums.LayoutMode.template,
        orientation: enums.Orientation.vertical,
    ),
)
```

[image]

However, if I add the `const` keyword in front of `SwitchPreview` as then something strange happens - if I load the app from scratch, or I do Restart though VS then the yellow square doesn't show up. If I save - causing hot reload - it shows up.

If I remove the `const` keyword then everything works.

Any idea why is that? What do I need to explore inside my `SwitchPreview` widget which is pretty straight forward?

Comment: its flutter behaviour. Flutter will not rebuild every constant widget. Thats why if you put `const` to your widget, everytime you do `hot reload` which means, the widget tree is rebuid, only dirty widget will rebuild.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't really explain why it would not load at initial app load and only on hot reload.